# Easily convert Map<String, Object> to Map<String, String>

Tags: java, dictionary, casting

An API I am using has a method that returns a `Map<String, Object>`, but I know the `Object`'s are `String`'s in this case, so I want it as a `Map<String, String>`.

But for some reason I can't just cast it, Java says `Map<String, Object>` cannot be casted to `Map<String, String>`, for some reason.

I used:

```
Map<String, Object> tempMap = someApiMethodReturningAMap();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String i : tempMap.keySet()) {
    map.put(i, String.valueOf(tempMap.get(i)));
}
```

as a workaround, but is there an easier way?

Comment: That's easy and understandable way, I would only recommend to change the cast to 'String.valueOf()' - you need to have a meaningful impl of  the toString() method of the Object arg.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well you can't *safely* cast it to a `Map<String, String>` because even though *you* know you've only got strings as the values, the compiler doesn't. That's like expecting:

```
Object x = "foo";
String y = x;
```

to work - it doesn't; you need to *explicitly* cast.

Likewise you can explicitly cast here, too, if you go via `Object`:

```
Map<String, Object> x = ...;
Map<String, String> y = (Map<String, String>) (Object) x;
```

Now you'll get a warning saying that it's an *unchecked* cast, because unlike the earlier "object to string" cast, there's no execution-time check that it's really valid. Type erasure means that a map doesn't really know its key/value types. So you end up with checking only being done when elements are fetched:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> x = new HashMap<>();
        x.put("foo", "bar");
        x.put("number", 0);
        Map<String, String> y = (Map<String, String>) (Object) x;
        // This is fine
        System.out.println(y.get("foo"));

        // This goes bang! It's trying to cast an Integer to a String
        System.out.println(y.get("number"));
    }
}
```

So if you really want to avoid creating a new map, this "cast via `Object`" will work - but it's far from ideal.

Your approach is safer, although you can make it slightly more efficient by avoiding the lookup:

```
public static Map<String, String> copyToStringValueMap(
        Map<String, Object> input) {
    Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : input.entrySet()) {
        ret.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A Java 8 solution:

```
private Map<String, String> stringifyValues(Map<String, Object> variables) {
    return variables.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (String) e.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Good solutions here, but I want to add another one that taking into consideration handling `null` values:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

Map<String,String> stringifiedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
             .filter(m -> m.getKey() != null && m.getValue() !=null)
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (String)e.getValue()));
```